# Salvar dados por websocket

Tags: php, angularjs, node.js, websocket

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema utilizando AngularJS e Websocket (PHP ou NodeJS estou definindo ainda), onde as informações dos formulários pretendo salvar via socket, ou seja, enviando um array com as informações e processando-as para salvar no banco de dados e retornando a confirmação, e da mesma forma quero trazer os dados via socket.

Estando todos os layouts tratados via AngularJS o mais comum é trazer via `$http()`, porém quero trazê-los via socket já que pretendo manter TODOS os clientes logados conectados.

Sei que isso tudo é possível, e já tenho algumas partes funcionando, o que quero realmente é saber os riscos que estou correndo com isso, questão de servidores não há problema, tudo elástico e auto-balance, questão é desempenho e dinâmica, vale a pena todo esse trabalho? A que ponto isso pode se tornar um problema?

Acrescentando... Quando um usuário salva algum conteúdo pertinente a um grupo, essa informação além de salva precisa ser imediatamente repassada para os demais participantes do grupo. Sei que podemos fazer requisições de Tempo em Tempo para verificar se há atualização e tal por ajax, mas acredito que fique mais dinâmico fazendo por socket.

Comment: Ao meu ver, websockets serve para aplicações em tempo real em que o servidor irá disparar a atualização e não o cliente. O que quero dizer é que operações como salvar os dados de um formulário que não implique na atualização em outros clientes pode ser feitas através de simples requisições AJAX. Acredito ser melhor usar websockets apenas onde realmente é necessário.

Comment: Você citou um ponto importante que esqueci de comentar, as atualizações geradas por 1 usuário precisam ser repassadas para os demais quando participam do mesmo grupo.

Comment: A questão toda é baseada na pergunta **saber os riscos que estou correndo com isso** e **vale a pena todo esse trabalho?**  **A que ponto isso pode se tornar um problema?**, então sinto muito mas todas as respostas serão baseadas em opniões pois não tem um problema em si, apenas obterá opniões de implementação do jeito que foi feito a pergunta